# C# lambda variable initialization

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Today for the first time I seen something similar to this:

```
private string m => string.Empty;
```

using lambda to initialize a variable. Why doing it like this and what are the benefits?

Comment: Please note that this syntax is only available in C# 6.0 language version.

Comment: Great new feature, adds more code brevity IMO!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's called *Expression-Bodied Properties* and it's merely a shortcut for getter-only properties:

```
private string m
{
    get { return string.Empty; }
}
```

As for the benefits of this approach, I guess you can treat it as syntactic sugar that is only saving you some keystrokes.

See [Roslyn Wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodies-on-property-like-function-members)

Comment: Not just saving keystrokes, but also easier to read if you have a lot of them - less clutter. (That is, assuming the reader is familiar with this syntax.)

Answer (score 12):

It's not a variable, it's an expression bodied property. A read-only property, in your case returning `string.Empty`.

It's the same as

```
private string m { get { return string.Empty; } }
```

It's one of the new features introduced in C# 6.0. The benefit is shorter, more concise code. Especially if you have a class with a lot of simple read-only properties.

If you want to see a real-world example of this syntax, check the [this post on Eric Lippert's blog](http://ericlippert.com/2015/12/03/the-dedoublifier-part-two/). As you can see, there's a lot of one-line methods and properties there. Without expression-bodied properties and members, the code would be much longer. And a considerable part of it would be curly braces.

Answer (score 5):

This is not actually a variable initialization, this binds the lambda expression "string.Empty" to "m", so whenever you dereference "m", it will actually evaluate your lambda expression.

For further reading check out [this github page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) (section "Expression-bodied function member")